# MaterialTabs not refreshing when i change viewpager's adapter

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

i'm trying to reload a viewpager's adapter, changing some parameters.
This my MainActivity's code:

```
private void createTabs() {

    String titles[] = new String[] {getResources().getString(R.string.man),
                                    getResources().getString(R.string.woman)};

    int icons[] = new int[] {R.mipmap.man, R.mipmap.woman};

    Main_Fragments_Adapter adapter = new Main_Fragments_Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                                                                this,
                                                                titles,
                                                                icons,
                                                                new Coordinates(this.latitude, this.longitude),
                                                                searchRange,
                                                                cutTypes);

    this.vpPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    this.mtTabs.setViewPager(this.vpPager);
}
```

And the adapter's code:

```
public class Main_Fragments_Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements MaterialTabs.CustomTabProvider {

private String[] TITLES;
private int[] ICONS;
private FragmentActivity activity;
private Coordinates coordinates;
private int searchRange;
private String cutTypes;

public Main_Fragments_Adapter(FragmentManager fm, FragmentActivity activity, String titles[], int icons[], Coordinates coordinates, int searchRange, String cutTypes) {
    super(fm);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.TITLES = titles;
    this.ICONS = icons;
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
    this.searchRange = searchRange;
    this.cutTypes = cutTypes;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return TITLES[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return TITLES.length;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putDouble("latitude", coordinates.getLatitude());
    bundle.putDouble("longitude", coordinates.getLongitude());
    bundle.putInt("searchRange", searchRange);
    bundle.putString("cut_types", cutTypes);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
        default:
            Main_Fragment_Man fragment_man = new Main_Fragment_Man();
            fragment_man.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment_man;
        case 1:
            Main_Fragment_Woman fragment_woman = new Main_Fragment_Woman();
            fragment_woman.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment_woman;
    }
}

@Override
public View getCustomTabView(ViewGroup parent, int position) {

    TextView textView = new TextView(this.activity);
    textView.setText(this.TITLES[position]);
    textView.setTextSize(24f);
    textView.setTextColor(this.activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    textView.setPadding(15, 0, 0, 0);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this.activity);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(this.activity.getResources().getDrawable(ICONS[position]));

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this.activity);
    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    linearLayout.addView(textView);

    return linearLayout;
}
```

}

There is custom dialog that receive the parameters for the adapter (searchRange and cutTypes) and call the createTabs() function. But, after that the parameters are changed, the fragments received the previuosly parameters. How can i solve it?